# Which one is appropriate?

Tags: grammar, tense, word-usage

Please help me out,

He is listening to the news

He is listening the news...

Explain it with reasons, it will be really kind of you!

Comment: Please help me out as soon as possible

Comment: You can edit your question with more information about what you don't understand and *why a dictionary (or other reference) didn't answer your question*. Editing also puts your question at the top of the home page, so more people will see it. (You should not abuse this ability just to get more views, but it can be very helpful if you weren't clear about what you didn't understand and need more specific answers.)

Comment: Besides: comments like "Please help me out as soon as possible" are frowned upon. We write answers purely out of goodwill (and sometimes a tiny bit because we are show-offs, at least I am), nobody gets paid here, so don't rush us!

Answer (score 3):

"He is listening to the news" is correct.

"Listening" is an intransitive verb. That is, it does not take an object. You cannot "listen [something]". You can "listen to [something]", but then "something" is an indirect object.

Note that if you are talking about printed news, you could say, "He is reading the news". "Reading" DOES take an object. You can also say, "He is hearing the news".

Note this has nothing to do with "news", but with "listening". You cannot say, "He is listening his wife", but rather should say, "He is listening to his wife", etc.

Most dictionaries will tell you whether a verb is transitive (takes an object) or intransitive (does not).

Answer (score 1):

The verb listen is an intransitive verb. You cannot listen something (without the preposition "to") just like you cannot go school without "to". So the correct sentence is "he is listening to the news".

Comment: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/listen_1?isEntryInOtherDict=true