# Should I use "is" or "was" in these sentences?

Tags: grammar, tense

I have a question about 'is' and 'was.'

> Elbert is absent, he might be busy.
>
> Elbert was absent, he might be busy.

Which one is correct?
What do they mean?

Comment: You need to provide more context and explain why you are confused.  Please read the feedback you were given on http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48623/which-one-is-appropriate  and http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48615/which-one-is-correct-can-to-be-used-here

Comment: @Pyraminx  - I have approved a couple of edits to this post, because they constitute incidental improvements.  They don't resolve the fundamental reason why it was closed in the first place, though, and are not really advancing its chances of being reopened.  The OP needs to explain what he thinks they mean, and why he is confused.  It seems like a trip to the dictionary should answer his question fully, since these are pretty straightforward constructions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to say that Elbert is away and still is, use 'is.'

> Elbert is absent(Elbert is and still is away).

But if you want to say that Elbert was away but is here now, or was absent yesterday, the use 'was.'

> Elbert was absent yesterday. (He didn't show up yesterday)
>   Elbert was absent, but he's here now. (He recently showed up)